# Inherit only the type from parent class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, oop, inheritance

Consider a parent class `Foo` and my class `myFoo`. I want that `isinstance(myFoo, Foo)` returns True, but without inheriting all the methods and attributes from `Foo`.

e.g.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # do stuff

    # tons of methods!

class myFoo:
    def __init__(self):
         # do stuff

    # couple of methods not in common with Foo
```

This is probably a niche use case, but it would be very handy for me. How can I 'fool' `isinstance` in believing that `myFoo` is a `Foo` instance without doing `class myFoo(Foo)` and thus inheriting the tons of methods from `Foo`.

**Edit with context:**

So in my case, `Foo` inherits from Mixin classes, each defining a bunch of related methods. Several of the methods defined in those Mixin start with `self if isinstance(self, Foo) else self.foo` because either `Foo` is provided, or a class with `Foo` set as a `.foo` attribute is provided.

Now, I want to define a different `myFoo` class which inherits only some of those Mixin. But they do not work as they check `isinstance(self, Foo)`. Changing the Mixin or the `Foo` class is not an option, so either I have to copy the entire Mixin and all the functions it might call and edit them; or I find a way to 'fool' the Mixin in believing that what I provide to it is indeed a `Foo` instance.

---

Alternatively, I could inherit from `Foo` and overwrite/raise `AttributeError` on calls to all the methods I do not want as part of `myFoo`.

Comment: Could you comment on why you want `isinstance(x, T)` to return `True` when `x` isn't actually an instance of `T`?

Comment: @Brian Find some context in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python implements the concept of "Virtual Subclassing" - which precisely allows a class to be declared as a subclass of another, without necessarily inheriting from that one. (that is, exactly your problem).

The only requirement is that the base class that will allow for virtual subclassing is created with abc.ABCMeta metaclass - even if you are not using abstract methods. It can be done using the lower level `__subclasscheck__` in a custom metaclass, but abc.ABC have it ready to work,including the `.register` call, which is also needed.

```
In [295]: import abc

In [296]: class Foo(abc.ABC):
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         # do stuff
     ...:         ...
     ...:     # tons of methods!
     ...:
     ...: class myFoo:
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:          # do stuff
     ...:          ...
     ...:

In [297]: Foo.register(myFoo)
Out[297]: __main__.myFoo

In [298]: issubclass(myFoo,Foo)
Out[298]: True

In [299]: isinstance(myFoo(), Foo)
Out[299]: True
```

As seen in the example above, the abc.ABC class has mechanisms in place to allow virtual subclassing, by adding a class-only "register" method. `myFoo` do not inherit from `Foo` in anyway in this example.

As for

> Alternatively, I could inherit from Foo and overwrite/raise
> AttributeError on calls to all the methods I do not want as part of
> myFoo.

That is possible, but a lot less practical - can be done by carefully overriding `__getattribute__` on the class, and taking care of a list of methods that should be hidden in the inherited class.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed what I was trying to do. Sadly Foo does not inherit from ABC, and I can't change it (Foo is inside a large third-party package, and a change would impact too many projects). So indeed, I chose to go with plan B and overriding `__getattribute__`. Still, thank you for this great answer and knowledge about virtual subclassing and `.register`!

Comment: but going the `__getattribute__` way means "isinstance" checks won't  do. If all the "isinstance"and "issubclass" check are on your side, you can create an empty `class BaseFoo(abc): ` on your code, and register both `Foo` and `myFoo`as subclasses of it, and perform the instance/subclass checks on `BaseFoo` instead

Comment: Good idea, but the problem is that all the checks are also not on my side.. I'm a bit unlucky here. So with the `__getattribute__` way, I've directly instanciated `myFoo` as `myFoo(Foo)`, which does pass all the methods and attributes from `Foo` to `myFoo`, but means `myFoo` passes `isinstance(myFoo, Foo)`. So now in `__getattribute__`, I'm catching all the calls to methods/attributes I do not want part of `myFoo`. Works.. but a hassle.

Comment: I was really hoping for an easy way to do something like: `class myFoo(type=Foo)`, or with a special attribute e.g. `__type__` or something like that. What you propose is the closest thing to it, and would have been very useful... if `Foo` did match the conditions for it!

Comment: sorry to hear that. there is not even a simple way to monkey patch  Foo to accept virtual subclassing as it is. (monkeypatch: add a feature to a class or object you do not directly control after it is declared). The support for virtual subclassing must be on the metaclass, and it can only be changed at class creation time - and then Foo would be a new object and all subclasses of it would need to be re-created as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a gross violation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle. Maybe you could extract a superclass that had the interface that you want and then have both classes inherit from it.

Comment: So my problem is I can not modify `Foo` or the `Mixin` it inherits from. Which is why I'm looking for a way to inherit the type only. Actually, it does not violate this principle, because `myFoo` and `Foo` represents the same thing, but `myFoo` represents less of it. Typically, `Foo` should inherit from `myFoo` and extend its capabilities; but for once, I need to do the inverse!

Comment: @Mathieu "Actually, it does not violate this principle, because myFoo and Foo represents the same thing, but myFoo represents less of it." that *is contradicting the LSP*

Comment: IMO, the LSP is over valued and "unfit for the real world". The fact is Python offers exactly the requested feature with the name of "virtual subclassing" (though this naming seems not to be used in other literature)